# Breaking a line

Tags: line-breaking

I usually break a line with `\\`. I have a piece of code:

```
\textbf{Headline}
\\
\\
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
```

The problem is Headline and Table get separated into different pages. What should I write to make them non-breaking?

Comment: Your Headline looks like a sectioning title, it wouldn’t be better to use a sectioning command? Usually sectioning commands avoid page breaking between the title and the contents, a table in this case

Comment: Your code should give lots of error. Why do you ignore them?

Comment: Possibly, you want your `Headline` to be a `\caption`, if you include both the caption and the tabular inside a `table` environment.

Comment: First, you should use things like `\medskip`, `\bigskip`, `\vspace{...}` or `\\[...]` to effect spacing instead of multiple lines (stop thinking like a typewriter).  Second, place things you want to keep together into an unbreakable box, like `\parbox` or a `minipage`.

Comment: John Kormylo, Thanks a lot.

Comment: outside of tables you should almost never use ``\\``  why are you using forced linebreaking here? Certainly you should never use two consecutive ``\\`` latex will have given warning sabout that.

Comment: use `\section*{Heading}` then latex knows it is a heading and will not break the page at that point,